# Are there any known issues using two jQuery on one page?

Tags: jquery, multiple-instances

we have a project that uses jQuery in noConflict mode. Users of this product uses their own version of jQuery. Result is that on page there are two versions of jQuery (one in noConflict(true) mode and another in normal/global mode).

Are there any known issues with this approach? Official documentation says

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended)...

but it doesn't say the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two or more versions of jQuery can be made to work, but only if it is done correctly and very carefully.  In general, it should be avoided if at all possible for the following reasons:

1. Loading multiple versions of jQuery takes longer to download and consumes more memory while the page is active.  The designers of jQuery who work pretty hard to get this much functionality in the amount of code they have probably cringe when they see people including multiple versions of jQuery and doubling or tripling the memory/download consumed.
2. You must very carefully and consistently access only the correct version of jQuery for any given piece of code.  Mixing versions within that same section of code can lead to unexpected issues.
3. You cannot share some types of data between versions. For example, if you set some info with `$(elem).data("key", info)` in one version of jQuery, that data will not be available in the other version of jQuery as they each have their own `.data()` repository.
4. You cannot share event handlers between versions.  For example if you do `.on()` with one version, and you try to do `.off()` with the other in order to clear all jQuery event handlers on a given object, you will only remove the event handlers installed in the current version of jQuery (again because each version of jQuery has it's own event handler storage), not the ones installed with the other.

Answer (score 0):

There are no problem, you can have a program with two or more jQuery version due to jQuery's noconflict mode.

By the way jQuery documentation says:

> "[..](which is not recommended)[..]"

This, in my opionion, because introduce new problem, you have to remember to use always a specific jQuery function specifying version:

```
jQuery_1_x_y('#el').function(); 
jQuery_1_k_z('#el').function();
```